# Why this function doesn't work for game coordinates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const gameBoardWidth = 28;
const gameBoardHeight = 16;
const gameBoardCoordinates = [...Array(gameBoardWidth)].map((e) =>
  Array(gameBoardHeight).fill(0),
);

const createCoordinates = () => {
  for (x = 0; x < gameBoardWidth * 50; x += 50) {
    for (y = 0; y < gameBoardWidth * 50; y += 50) {
      gameBoardCoordinates[x][y].x = x;
      gameBoardCoordinates[x][y].y = y;
    }
  }
};
```

when calling this function gameBoardCoordinates elements always have y:15.

Comment: actually, calling this function throws an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'x')
    at createCoordinates (<anonymous>:10:36)". A debugger can tell you why.

Comment: i think there must be an error on `.x=x` in second loop.
error is: Cannot set properties of undefined.

Comment: error bcz when first loop start there is x and y is both 0 but when inner loop y+=50 add y counter to 50 and there is no indexed value available on `gameBoardCoordinates`  x = 0 and y = 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that will initialise your coordinates (I reduced the board size to make it more manageable):

```js
const gameBoardWidth = 8;
const gameBoardHeight = 
6;
const gameBoardCoordinates = [...Array(gameBoardHeight)].map((e) =>
  Array(gameBoardWidth).fill(0),
);

const createCoordinates = () => {
  for (y = 0; y < gameBoardHeight; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < gameBoardWidth; x++) {
      gameBoardCoordinates[y][x]={x:x*50,y:y*50};
    }
  }
};

createCoordinates();
console.log(gameBoardCoordinates)
```